# Firebase read: "$uid == auth.uid" giving error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Auth id exist in the Authentication. Still I am getting this error while trying this -

> DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(authResult.getUser().getUid());

My database looks like this - 
[image] 
Rule looks like this - 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try `"$uid === auth.uid"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue android code looks like this -

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(authResult.getUser().getUid());
```